# Unreal Engine Beginner FMath::Sin

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Okay, so I'm currently learning an [Unreal Engine programming tutorial](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/QuickStart/3/index.html). Here is the code I'm confused with:

```
void AFloatingActor::Tick( float DeltaTime )
{
    Super::Tick( DeltaTime );
    FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation();
    float DeltaHeight = (FMath::Sin(RunningTime + DeltaTime) - FMath::Sin(RunningTime));
    NewLocation.Z += DeltaHeight * 20.0f; // Scale our height by a factor of 20
    RunningTime += DeltaTime;
    SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
}
```

I don't understand the part where it says this:

```
void AFloatingActor::Tick( float DeltaTime )
{
    Super::Tick( DeltaTime );
```

and this part:

```
float DeltaHeight = (FMath::Sin(RunningTime + DeltaTime) - FMath::Sin(RunningTime));
    NewLocation.Z += DeltaHeight * 20.0f; // Scale our height by a factor of 20
```

What does it do? How does it do that? What is FMath::Sin? It's so confusing.

That's it! Thank you for your time (and hopefully, help)!

Comment: "*I don't understand*"  is not a good description of what the issue is.  That could mean anything from not understanding C++, to not understanding what `::`, does, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Super::Tick( DeltaTime );` is calling the `Tick` method of the parent class with the `Super` keyword.

`DeltaTime` is the amount of time that is passed between in each frame in the engine, a very common and necessary concept in game development that you can learn more about [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/Tick/1/index.html).

Now lets look at :

```
float DeltaHeight = (FMath::Sin(RunningTime + DeltaTime) - 
    FMath::Sin(RunningTime));
    NewLocation.Z += DeltaHeight * 20.0f; // Scale our height by a factor of 20
```

`float DeltaHeight` creates a new `float` variable on the stack

```
= (FMath::Sin(RunningTime + DeltaTime) - 
    FMath::Sin(RunningTime));
```

uses the `FMath::Sin` `Sin` method of the `FMath` class to do a basic sin calculation. You can do an easy [tutorial on sin and cosine here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sine-cosine-tangent.html)

And finally lets look at

```
   NewLocation.Z += DeltaHeight * 20.0f;
```

`NewLocation` is an `FVector`, which is Unreal's version of a Vector. All this line does is add the previously calculated `float` called `DeltaHeight` to the `Z` value of `NewLocation`, as well as scaling that value by 20.

To learn more about basic vector math I would recomend [The Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/) by Daniel Shiffman.

Answer (score 2):

FMath is used in the UE4 API for alot of core math functions. FMath::Abs gives you the aboslute (psotive value for example)

FMath::Sin means your using a sin function from the FMath class. :: means inheriting from or "coming from" so think of it as "FMath has a function im calling called Sin"

Super::Tick(DeltaTime); just means your actor class is ticking (executing every frame) within the tick function.